# Angular js resize Openlayers 3 map from watch function

Tags: angularjs, openlayers-3

I have an Openlayers 3 map that should re-size using a watch function when the user re-sizes the browser. When the map initially loads the map is stretched vertically but when I resize the browser it's correct.

When I Inspect the canvas element initially it shows:

```
<canvas class="ol-unselectable" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" width="1090" height="550"></canvas>
```

Then after the resize it responds to the correct size:

```
<canvas class="ol-unselectable" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" width="1086" height="1004"></canvas>
```

All the information I can find points to calling  map.updateSize(); but this doesn't seem to work and the height values don't seem to change. Any help would be appreciated.

```
wmm.directive('tchOlMap', ['$window', function ($window) {

var MAP_DOM_ELEMENT_ID = 'tchMap';

return {
    //restrict: 'E',
    scope: false,
    //replace: true,

    template: '<div id="' + MAP_DOM_ELEMENT_ID +'" class="full-height" ng-style="mStyle"></div>',

    link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.style = {};


      // these functions set the map and other divs to the size of the browser dynamically
      var w = angular.element($window);                

        scope.getWindowDimensions = function () {
        return { 'h': w.height(), 'w': w.width() };
        };


       scope.$watch(scope.getWindowDimensions, function (newValue, oldValue) {

        scope.mStyle = { 
                'height': (newValue.h - 102) + 'px',
                'width': '100%'
            };


             console.log('new height '+newValue.h);
           console.log('old height '+newValue.h);

           console.log(map.getSize());
           map.updateSize();

    }, true);
```

I have tried using $apply as follows but this doesn't work

```
scope.$apply(function() {
                  map.updateSize(); 
               });
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my case which is similar to yours.
My environment (package.json):

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "6.1.1",
  "@angular/common": "6.1.1",
  "@angular/compiler": "6.1.1",
  "@angular/core": "6.1.1",
  "@angular/forms": "6.1.1",
  "@angular/http": "6.1.1",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "6.1.1",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.1.1",
  "@angular/router": "6.1.1",
  "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
  "core-js": "^2.4.1",
  "jquery": "^1.9.1",
  "moment": "^2.22.2",
  "moment-timezone": "^0.5.21",
  "ol": "^5.1.3",
  "ol-geocoder": "^3.2.0",
  "ol-layerswitcher": "git+https://github.com/walkermatt/ol-layerswitcher.git#ol5",
  "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
  "rxjs": "^6.2.2",
  "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
}
```

I made my component to implement 'DoCheck':

1. import 'DoCheck' in the Component

`import {DoCheck} from '@angular/core';`

2. Implement 'ngDoCheck' method in the component

Offical definition(https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks):

> Detect and act upon changes that Angular can't or won't detect on its own.
>   Called during every change detection run, immediately after ngOnChanges() and ngOnInit().

For my case, I need it to update map size when first loading map and spliting the page by adding another panel on the right side.

`ngDoCheck() { this.map.updateSize();}`

For your case, you probably can do in this way in the controller (not tested):

```
this.$doCheck = function() { map.updateSize(); };
```

> https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

Answer (score -1):

Use the below code. We are calling map.updateSize() function inside setTimeout() function with value 200ms. After loading this script, map.updateSize() will be executed after 200ms and your map will load on the browser

window.onload = function() { setTimeout( function(){ map.updateSize(); },200); }

Comment: This was my first answer on stackoverflow. I did included the explanation. Hope it will help you.